# Parse out ^M characters

Tags: macos, cocoa

I've got a Cocoa app that parses text from a standard text file.  When using terminal programs like nano and pico to edit the file, I'll sometimes notice that a `^M` character shows up. I can't reproduce this on later versions of Mac OS X, but it seems to abound in version 10.5.

Oddly, when I take a file that has the `^M` character in it from a 10.5 system, it magically goes away in 10.6+; I'm assuming this is because Mac OS started to convert the linux-style linefeeds into Mac-style (??).  Consequently, it has made it somewhat complex to fix the problem at debug-time since I have XCode only installed on 10.7.

I need a way to find the `^M` character and replace it with something more standard (like `\n`) while I'm parsing the file. What type of character do I need to look for? It doesn't seem to be a \n and likewise, no combination of \r\n seems to do the trick either. The `^M` still hangs around.

Answer (score 1):

This is easy to manage within XCode.

Simply select the file you want to change the line endings for and then open up the utilities panel and you can change the Line Endings.

Like so:

[image]

Comment: I need to do this at run-time though. Some people running the app use nano to edit the file and then end up with the Dos style line-feeds. I can't really ask them to mail me their file... ;) Is there a way to do this using objective-c?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a MacOS user, in general, so I'm only guessing this will work.  On typical Unix-like systems, you can use Ctrl-V to get the next control character you enter to appear as a visible character sequence.  Thus, for instance, you might be able to get the ^M you want to appear by first entering Ctrl-V, then pressing your Return key.  Note that the ^M that appears on your screen in this case is not the same (from the perspective of your software) as the ^M that appears when you first enter the ^ character then the M character.  In this manner, you can do things like use regular expressions to replace that ^M control character representation with instances of \n instead.

You could also, as Jakrabbit suggests, use dos2unix to filter the file -- assuming it's available on your Mac.

Answer (score 1):

"^M" is a representation of the ASCII line feed character. This is character code 13 in ASCII (and UTF-8), so when parsing the file, look for characters with a value of 13 and just ignore them.

Answer (score 0):

^M is the standard carriage return character in DOS/Windows.

I would just use the dos2unix program to get rid of them all.

Comment: Oh Sure.  I think you just need to replace "\r" with ""; just remove the "\r"